# Snort 'make install' error on Linux

Tags: linux, snort

I'm trying to install Snort on Debian and I get this error after 'make install':

```
make[6]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicengine'
 /bin/bash ../../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libsf_engine.la '/usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicengine'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsf_engine.so.0.0.0 /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicengine/libsf_engine.so.0.0.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot remove '/usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicengine/libsf_engine.so.0.0.0': Permission denied
Makefile:558: recipe for target 'install-dynamicengineLTLIBRARIES' failed
make[6]: *** [install-dynamicengineLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/caleb/snort-2.9.9.0/src/dynamic-plugins/sf_engine'
Makefile:786: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[5]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/caleb/snort-2.9.9.0/src/dynamic-plugins/sf_engine'
Makefile:623: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/caleb/snort-2.9.9.0/src/dynamic-plugins/sf_engine'
Makefile:780: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[3]: *** [install] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/caleb/snort-2.9.9.0/src/dynamic-plugins/sf_engine'
Makefile:434: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/caleb/snort-2.9.9.0/src/dynamic-plugins'
Makefile:540: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/caleb/snort-2.9.9.0/src'
Makefile:505: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Adding 'sudo' before the command did the job.

```
sudo make install
```